# Connect internally to a Virtual Machine with SQL Server from Web Sites using Windows Azure

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using Windows Azure Web Sites to host my web application and also have a Windows Azure Virtual Machine with SQL Server on it. I would like to connect internally from Windows Azure Web Sites to my Virtual Machine, but using the supplied internal IP address of my Virtual Machine is not working. Is it possible to connect internally from Web Sites to a Virtual Machine? If so, how can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope!

The only way to internally connect that different resources is via Azure Virtual Network. And as of today, Web Sites does not support Virtual Network. Cloud Services however do support Virtual Network, as do Virtual Machines. So if you move your deployment to Cloud Service (Web Role) you will be able to connect it to the VM via internal IP Address and never have to go "out".

My believe (and my speculation) that we might eventually see in the future Web Sites being able to connect to Azure Virtual Network, at least for the Reserved Instances.